# directory structure in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I am learning Aurelia framework, and have come across this code:

```
import moment from "moment";

export class DateFormatValueConverter {
    toView(value) {
        return moment(value).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
    }
}
```

My question is, where does it expect to find `moment` in the first statement? I am getting this error:

```
aurelia-logging-console.js:86 ERROR [app-router] Error: XHR error (404
Not Found) loading http://localhost:9000/dist/moment.js(…)
```

I then tried doing `npm install moment --save` and can now see this in my package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.12.0",
    "numeral": "^1.5.3"
  }
```

But the error persists. Can someone please explain where should I store `moment`?

Update: I looked into the `dist` directory according to the error, but I am not sure how that's populated. It contains exactly same files as in my `src` directory, but how does that work?

Comment: are you using systemjs or webpack?

Comment: I am following this tutorial. http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/binding/1.0.0-beta.1.2.1/doc/article/binding-value-converters 
Till now I have used `npm` and `jspm` according to the tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to install it using jspm, not npm. Like this:

```
jspm install moment;
```

Then, you will be able to load:

```
import moment from "moment";
```

Comment: I have one doubt, though. When do we use `npm` and when to use `jspm`? I remember doing `npm install` at the start of the tutorial.

Comment: You should use npm to install build tools, like `gulp`, `jspm` and some other things. To install libraries, which would be used by your application, you should use JSPM. However, the webpack skeleton, which is another approach to develop in Aurelia, doesn't use JSPM. In that case, you should NPM to install build tools and libraries.

Comment: In short, when you installed npm packages via `npm install` you were installing jspm. When you installed jspm packages via `jspm install -y`, you were installing aurelia, jquery, etc.

Comment: I'm having this same issue. I'm using the typescript template. I have run these commands `jspm install` `typings install --ambient --save`. Running `gulp build` I'm getting `Cannot find module 'moment'.` and `Cannot find namespace 'moment'.` Any idea how to solve this? Seemingly though `import moment = require('moment')` will work